# R - regex, replace string between '

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I tried to find a solution for this for a very long time and any other question with this topic just wouldn't give me the needed answer.
I am trying to replace the string between ' ' with an empty string, so deleting it.

I have

```
    pattern <- "      'ABV22341.1 profilin-like protein'"
```

and I am trying to use gsub() like

```
    gsub(*insert regex here*, "", pattern)
```

but I am struggling to find a matching expression, I only find expressions that match everything except the whitespaces at the beginning.

Is there a good solution? I would really appreciate it!

**Edit**

The desired output would be

```
    [1] "      ''"
```

Comment: So what exactly was that expression?

Comment: I found `gsub("\'.*\'", "", pattern)` as an expression, which also matches the ', which I don't want

Comment: Whoops, sorry, yes, I've copied the exclusion across from the example.  +1 to you.

Comment: Can you please edit the question so that we're provided with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Use `gsub("'[^']*'", "''", pattern)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! never thought about this solution..

Comment: You are welcome. No backreferences are even necessary here.